# Use Regular Expression to find files ending with / without certain types of extension

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expression to find files ending with certain types of extensions but fails.

Let's consider below are some existing files:

```
123.htm  
123.exe  
123.rmvb  
123.html  
123.HTM  
123.HTML
```

I just want to the expression returns:

- only `123.htm` and `123.HTM` (without returning `123.html` and `123.HTML`)
- only `123.exe`, `123.rmvb`, `123.html` and `123.HTML`

For the first, I tried `123\.(htm|HTM)$`, please refer to [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/s7txjH/1)
For the second, I tried `123\.[^(htm|HTM)]$`, please refer to [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/V4nvaW/1)
But both fails.

Do anyone have ideas? Thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: Your first regex is correct - https://regex101.com/r/s7txjH/2. The second one should be [`(?i)123\.[^.]+$(?<!\.htm)`](https://regex101.com/r/V4nvaW/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But why in demo 1, there is no any hightlight matches...

Comment: Because you used regex101 incorrectly - you forgot to use `m` modifier since you are testing a multiline string, not separate strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct, you just did not test the pattern correctly at regex101.com (you need to test with an `m` modifier that makes `^` match the start of a line and `$` to match the end of the line).

So, for the first one, `123\.(htm|HTM)$` or `123\.(?:htm|HTM)$` or `/123\.htm$/i` or `(?i)123\.htm$` will do depending on what regex engine you are using.

The second one is a bit trickier: you cannot use a sequence of chars inside a character class, these sequences are matched as separate chars. To match the end of the string not ending with the specific `htm` substring, you may use any pf the two:

```
(?i)123\.[^.]+$(?<!\.htm)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/V4nvaW/2). Or

```
(?i)123\.(?!htm$)[^.]+$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V4nvaW/3). The `i` case insensitive modifier would be especially handy with the lookbehind version, `$(?<!\.htm)`, where the check is performed once the end of string is reached. With the negative lookahead version, the check is performed after matching the `.` after `123`.